# Поиск элемента с минимальным значением в каждой нечетной строке матрицы

Tags: c, массивы, матрицы

Задание: Задать с клавиатуры целочисленную матрицу NxM. Найти в каждой нечетной
строке матрицы элемент с минимальным значением. Вывести на экран позиции и значения найденных элементов.

Вот код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main () {
int n,m;
int mas2[4][4];

for (n = 1; n<4; n++)
        {
            for (m = 1; m<4; m++)
  {
        printf ("mas2[%d,%d] = ", n,m);
            scanf ("%d", &mas2[n] [m]); // Ввод массива
  }
        }
         for (n = 1; n<4; n++)
        {
            for (m = 1; m<4; m++)
        {
        printf ("%d ", mas2[n] [m]); // Вывод массива
        }
        printf ("\n");
        }
         for (n = 1; n <4; n++)
        {
        for (m = 1; m <4; m++)
        {
            if ((n) % 2 != 0)
            {
            printf ("mas2[%d,%d] = %d\n", n,m,mas2[n] [m]); // Вывод нечетных строк
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод нечетных строк я организовал, не получается вывести позиции и значения элементов с минимальном значением в этих строчках.

Comment: `your_variable % 2 == 0` - это вроде четные всегда были

Comment: Спасибо, поправил

Comment: Предпоследний заголовок цикла *for (n = 1; n <4; n++)* лучше записать так: *for (n = 1; n <4; n+=2)*. ТОгда оператор *if* станет ненужным.

Comment: Собственно по вопросу о том, как искать минимум. Первое : заведите две целые переменные - в первой будет храниться текущее значение предполагаемого минимума, а во второй - положение в строке этого самого минимума. Перед началом выполнения самого внутреннего цикла (где Вы сейчас просто печатает элементы строки) присвойте этим переменным значение первого элемента в строке и "1".  Внутри цикла проверяйте, а может очередной элемент - меньше запомненного? И, если так, то присваивайте новые значения этой паре переменных. По завершению цикла у Вас будет минимальное значение в строке и его положение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нумерация элементов массива в си начинается с нуля, то есть mas[4] состоит из элементов mas[0] - mas[3]. Если нечётными строками считать строки mas2[1][m] и mas2[3][m] то:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
int n,m,min, pos;
int mas2[4][4];

for (n = 0; n<4; n++){
    for (m = 0; m<4; m++){
        printf ("mas2[%d,%d] = ", n,m);
        scanf ("%d", &mas2[n] [m]); // Ввод массива
}}
for (n = 0; n<4; n++){
    for (m = 0; m<4; m++){
        printf ("%d ", mas2[n] [m]); // Вывод массива
}
    printf ("\n");}
for (n = 1; n < 4; n += 2){ // нечётные строки
    min = mas2[n][0];
    pos = 0
    for (m = 1; m < 4; m++){
        if(min > mas2[n][m]){
            min = mas2[n][m];
            pos = m;}}
    printf ("mas2[%d,%d] = %d\n", n, pos, min); // Вывод
}
return 0;}
```